# IE8 window size problem

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript code :

```
function openQueryWindow(val)
{
    var wName       = "....";
    var srcHeight = screen.Height - 100;
    var srcWeight = screen.width  - 100;
    var dLeft = 50
    var dTop=25 
    var sFile=".....";
    window.open(sFile,wName,"scrollbars=1,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,width=" + srcWeight + ",height=" + srcHeight + ",top="+dTop+",left="+dLeft+",alwaysRaised") 
}
```

this code works in pop-up window in IE7 but doesn't work in IE8 and the pop-up window seems uncontrollable! How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can force IE8 to render HTML as IE7 does...
add this in  as close to opening  tag as possible

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

[here full article](http://ekdd.co.il/force-ie-7-rendering-in-ie-8/)

Comment: Term "It should" doesn't go well with Microsoft Browsers.

Comment: Thanx,, but is that a permanent solution..? because we're running an Enterprise Java Project and some of our users use IE7 that doesn't have any problem, in IE8 when the pop-up window shows up, you can't do anything with it because the maximize button is disabled and you can't control the size..!

Comment: All what it does it forces IE above 7 to user 7's engine to render and it is permanent.IE8 was a failure but in case of IE9 i'm not sure whether to use 7th or 9th.